# Resolving the circular dependency issue I have between two plugins

Tags: java, circular-dependency

I have a class called `Manhunt` that inherits `Minigame`. To keep the code and post brief, I'm only including the pertinent methods

```
public abstract class Minigame {

    public abstract void startCountdown();

}
```

```
public class Manhunt extends Minigame {

    @Override
    public void startCountdown() {

    }
    
}
```

And Minigame is handled by `MinigameManager`

```
public class MinigameManager {

    public void startMinigame(String minigame, int gameKey) {
        switch (minigame) {
            case "manhunt":
                UUID runner = this.playersQueued.remove(this.random.nextInt(this.playersQueued.size()));
                this.minigame = new Manhunt(gameKey, runner, this.playersQueued);
                this.minigame.startCountdown();
                this.playersQueued.clear();
                break;
            case "tbr":
            case "boatracer":
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, `Manhunt` and `MinigameManager` are in two separate plugins meaning this current setup requires IntelliJ to add dependencies for both programs that reference each other, leading to a circular dependency problem. I want to keep them separated in case I add extra Minigames (I just have to drag and drop extra Minigames as opposed to coding them all in the same program), but how do I resolve this circular dependency issue?

It seems like the Dependency Inversion Principle should solve this problem, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that to my program. Would I need to create an interface for `MinigameManager` or `Minigame`? I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through making the code more modular.

Comment: You would typically create a Service or Registry, to which games can register themselves, and the manager would only list the games available in its registry.

Comment: @Polygnome Uh, this is for a Minecraft plugin I'm making and the server just automatically registers any plugin inside the plugins folder, if that's what you're saying...

Comment: Yes and no. have the MiniGameManager be its own plugin. Then have the ManHunt be a separate plugin. Load order is important, load MiniGameManager first. Then load ManHunt. Have ManHunt register itself with MiniGameManager on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MinigameManager` needs to be in a separate third plugin.

`MinigameManager` depends on `Minigame`, but `Minigame` does not depend on `MinigameManager`. Since there is no co-dependency, there is no reason to have the two in the same library.

`MinigameManager` will then depend on both `Minigame` and `Manhunt`, and `Manhunt` will still also depend on `Minigame`.

Alternatively, you could go with a "registry" type approach where `MinigameManager` exports an interface that `Manhunt` implements, and then some runtime code in `MinigameManager` performs some magic to enumerate and instantiate any type that implements its interface. This is a common approach in Java, but be clear: **that is not cleanly separating dependencies.** That is simply transforming an *explicit dependency*, which must follow cleanly-defined rules and results in a clear and easy-to-see structure, into an *implicit dependency* which enables you to hide important structure and sidestep DAG validation and protections.

Comment: So creating a completely separate plugin for `MinigameManager` will solve the issue?

Comment: It will solve the circular dependency issue - the way to break cycles in a dependency graph is to split up the dependencies.

If there are other problems, you'll have to solve those next :)